# How to use variable PV from one .bb file to another bbappend file, when both files are in the samemetalyer?

Tags: global-variables, yocto, recipe

I have a metalyer `M_layer` containing one `xyz.bb` file and one `abc.bbapppend` file.
I want to save `PV` from `xyz.bb` file in a variable or a text file and use in `abc.bbappend` file.

I have tried various ways to store the `PV` in variable and fetch it in bbappend layer, but I am not able to do it.

Currently I am trying saving the `PV` in following ways:

```
echo "{$PV}" > "${LAYERDIR}/my_var.txt"   ---- in .bb
my_var2 = "${LAYERDIR}/my_var.txt"   --- in .bbappend file
```

But it doesn't work.

Expected result: `my_var2  = 3.r.f.g`

Actual result: `my_var2 = "${LAYERDIR}/my_var.txt"`

Instead of getting the exact version, I get the text mentioned within quote as it is.

Comment: Maybe you can just set `MY_GLOBAL_PV = "3.r.f.g"` in `local.conf` then set `PV = "${MY_GLOBAL_PV}"` in `xyz.bb` recipe?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Anything you do in one recipe is local to that recipe and its own appends. Always remember the OE base rule #1:

> "Recipe data is local, conf data is global".

So the only halfways correct way would be lifting the `PV` into the configuration by setting it globally, for example as a `PREFERRED_VERSION`.

Update:
You basically would do this by setting

> PREFERRED_VERSION_xyz = "1.2.3"

in some config file. This should then be visible in all recipes, you can check by using `bitbake -e abc` for example.

Comment: But there are PV of several other recipes too in th esame metalayer. How do I choose to save this perticular PV in conf/layer.conf???

Comment: I think I didnot convey my problem clearly. Ihave already assinged value to my PV like PV=1.2.3.4. Now i want to save this value of PV globally. If i have to write the version number in config file, i want to use variable where the value is saved instead of the version 1.2.3.4 itself???

Comment: You did "convey" the problem, but what I'm trying to tell you is that the solution approach is fundamentally flawed. You are not supposed to pass data from a recipe to another recipe in OpenEmbedded technology. Even worse, think about trying to build with the layers being read-only? To get a proper and reproductible solution, you have to rethink your approach in general, and I tried to hand you a possible way.